# adding custom "+" to many ggplot plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am constructing multiple ggplot plots and all of them have the same annotation. I have a time series plot and on certain days I annotate a verticle line. So say I have daily data such that I have the following plot:

```
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = depVar)) +
  geom_line()
```

I want to draw verticle lines at certain dates so I add the following:

```
      ggplot(aes(x = date, y = depVar)) +
      geom_line()
annotate("rect", xmin = as.Date("2016-03-09"), xmax = as.Date("2016-03-11"), 
         ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, alpha = .5)
```

which fills in the days from 09 to 11th of March 2016. I have many of these `annotate` parts and adding them takes up a lot of code. i.e.

```
      ggplot(aes(x = date, y = depVar)) +
      geom_line()
annotate("rect", xmin = as.Date("2016-03-09"), xmax = as.Date("2016-03-11"), 
         ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, alpha = .5) +
annotate("rect", xmin = as.Date("2017-01-03"), xmax = as.Date("2017-02-01"), 
         ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, alpha = .5) +
annotate("rect", xmin = as.Date("2018-01-03"), xmax = as.Date("2018-02-01"), 
         ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, alpha = .5) +
annotate("rect", xmin = as.Date("2019-03-09"), xmax = as.Date("2019-03-11"), 
         ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, alpha = .5) +
annotate("rect", xmin = as.Date("2020-03-09"), xmax = as.Date("2020-03-11"), 
         ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, alpha = .5)
```

Especially when I have multiple different time series plots I want to add the same `annotate` additions to. So how can I define the `annotate`s into a function and just call on them such as:

```
      ggplot(aes(x = date, y = depVar)) +
      geom_line() +
my_annotations()
```

I have tried:

```
my_annotations <- function(protocol_fill_color = "grey25"){
ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, alpha = .5) %+replace%
    annotate("rect", xmin = as.Date("2018-01-03"), xmax = as.Date("2018-02-01"), 
             ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, alpha = .5) %+replace%
    annotate("rect", xmin = as.Date("2019-03-09"), xmax = as.Date("2019-03-11"), 
             ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, alpha = .5) %+replace%
    annotate("rect", xmin = as.Date("2020-03-09"), xmax = as.Date("2020-03-11"), 
             ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, alpha = .5)  
}
```

But I cannot seem to get this to work.

EDIT: Reproducible data:

```
library(tidyquant)
d <- tq_get("IBM")

d %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = open)) +
  geom_line() +
  annotate("rect", xmin = as.Date("2012-03-09"), xmax = as.Date("2016-03-11"), 
           ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, alpha = .5) +
  annotate("rect", xmin = as.Date("2017-01-03"), xmax = as.Date("2017-04-01"), 
           ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, alpha = .5)
```

Comment: would it maybe be esier to create a dataframe with the rect details (xmin, xmax etc) and use one call to geom_rect

Comment: That does sound easier. I am not sure how to go about this. Should I just create a dates column and then a separate column with 0 and 1s in it to indicate the periods it should be annoteded or shaded?

Comment: create data like `rect_dat = data.frame(xmin=as.Date(c("2016-03-09", "2017-01-03")),
                      xmax=as.Date(c("2016-03-11", "2017-02-01")))` and then plot `p + geom_rect(data=rect_dat, 
              aes(ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf, xmin=xmin, xmax=xmax), 
              inherit.aes = 0, fill="red", alpha=0.5)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to annotate the same periods across all your plots, you could do this with a function like...

```
plot_1 <- d %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = open)) +
  geom_line()

add_blocks <- function(my_plot) {

  my_plot + 
    annotate("rect", xmin = as.Date("2012-03-09"), xmax = as.Date("2016-03-11"), 
             ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, alpha = .5) +
    annotate("rect", xmin = as.Date("2017-01-03"), xmax = as.Date("2017-04-01"), 
             ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, alpha = .5)

}

add_blocks(plot_1)
```

That produces this plot:

[image]